# numpy multidimensional (3d) matrix multiplication

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, multidimensional-array, matrix-multiplication

I get two 3d matrix A (32x3x3) and B(32x3x3), and I want to get matrix C with dimension 32x3x3. The calculation can be done using loop like:

```
a = numpy.random.rand(32, 3, 3)
b = numpy.random.rand(32, 3, 3)
c = numpy.random.rand(32, 3, 3)

for i in range(32):
    c[i] = numpy.dot(a[i], b[i])
```

I believe there must be a more efficient one-line solution to this problem. Can anybody help, thanks.

Comment: do you mean elementwise multiplication, or matrix multiplication by *layers*?

Comment: Why the downvote? The question is sensible and clear, IMO.

Comment: @AlvaroP since OP is using `dot`, looks like multiplication by layers is the intention. I believe some smart reshape/multiply/reshape-back can achieve the desired result, but not so sure.

Comment: @heltonbiker You're probably right. Maybe `tensordot`?http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html

Comment: @AlvaroP After personal testing, `tensordot` seems not work...

Answer (score 4):

You could do this using [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html):

```
In [142]: old = orig(a,b)

In [143]: new = np.einsum('ijk,ikl->ijl', a, b)

In [144]: np.allclose(old, new)
Out[144]: True
```

One advantage of using `einsum` is that you can almost read off what it's doing from the indices: leave the first axis alone (`i`), and perform a matrix multiplication on the last two `(jk,kl->jl)`).